# what is smooth embedding

Tags: differential-geometry

I know definition but I don't use this definiton to solve question
for example;

$f : R → R^3$ given by $f(t) = (cos(2πt),sin(2πt), t)$

I showed that this is an injective immersion but this is a smooth embedding?I dont realize what is $F(R)$ How can I show it?

Defn of smooth embedding: Let $F: M\rightarrow N$. If $F$ is a immersion and $M$ is a homeomorphic to $F(M)$ then F is called smooth embedding

Comment: I think if you draw what $f(\mathbf{R})$ looks like, you will quickly know whether it's homeomorphic to $\mathbf{R}$.  To prove it, you could look for a continuous map in the other direction (from $f(\mathbf{R})$ to $\mathbf{R}$) which would be an inverse to $f$.

Comment: @HewWolff Thank you for your answer. But my real problem is that I can not sketch f(R)

Comment: OK, I suggest you start with something simpler.  Define $g: \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}^2$, $g(t) = (\cos(2\pi t), \sin(2\pi t))$.  You can try out values of $t$ to get a feel for this function, or look it up under the name "wrapping function" if that helps.  Once you understand $g$, $f$ should be easier.

Comment: could $g$ be circle?

Comment: Yes, $g$ wraps the real line $\mathbf{R}$ around a circle, so its image $g(\mathbf{R})$ is a circle.  Now you need to visualize what $f$ does.

Comment: look like cylinder?